# How to get native login with Auth0?

Tags: facebook-login, auth0

I am using Ionic2 and have FB login in my app. Currently my app logs users in by opening a web view to FB login but I would like it to use the native FB app to login. Any ideas on how to achieve this? I have this for the auth0 setup.

```
auth0 = new Auth0({
    domain: 'xxxx.com',
    clientID: 'xxxxxx',
    callbackOnLocationHash: true
});
```

Comment: Have you checked the following documentation: [Lock iOS: Native Social Authentication](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/lock-ios/native-social-authentication)?

Comment: I guess I have overlooked this. Thanks for the link! ;)